# How to Show the progress bar while the url is loading in WebView Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, webview

**MainActivity.java**

 Okay, so this is where I load the url now progress bar is visible till the page is loaded and now when I click the links on the page, the progress bar does not appear, I'm searching a fix from 10 hours but none of them are suitable to this conditiion, the progress bar should start as the new url is loaded.
Please Help!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private WebView mWebView; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new com.c.MyAppWebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }});



}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}



public void aus (MenuItem menuItem){

    findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

}

public void cus (MenuItem menuItem){
    findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar

        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What kind of layout is your main layout?

Comment: Linear layout <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: should the webview disappear while its loading?

Comment: no, should not I just want progress to be visible when user clicks any link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just want the progress bar to appear over the web view when loading change your layout to a RelativeLayout. Put the progress bar on the bottom so it is draw at the top of the view hierarchy.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You also need to override a method on your webview client

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new com.c.MyAppWebViewClient() { 

    @Override 
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } 
});
```

Comment: The progress bar is not in the centre now.

Comment: This should be enough. I changed the xmlns so it should work

Comment: Is the problem just it's not centered now?

Comment: no, it's centered now, but nothing has changed, it don't show up when I click a url on the webpage!

Comment: No problem, Happy to help!

Comment: hey do you have any idea how to start a new layout if there is no internet connection?

Comment: You will have to start a new question for that but I imagine there's something like Onpagefailed that you can use

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                loadingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadingBar.bringToFront();
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                loadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
```

and add this to your xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <WebView
       android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:visibility="gone"
       android:id="@+id/purchase_loadingbar">
       <ProgressBar
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please can you explain how to implement this in my java code?